# Why is a bad practice to access DAO directly from a Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, dao

I was reading a topic about good practices on web development with Java and found that it is a bad practice to call the DAO from a Servlet. The topic itself did not explained why this is a bad practice, although it clearly explains that, following the best practices, we need a intermediate class (eg.: a service class) to call the DAO.

Why is this a bad practice? Is there any theorical and / or technical explanation to this?

Comment: Why have a DAO class at all? Why not put the queries directly into the Servlet?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Why have a Servlet? Why not implement a custom web server? ;)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch pah custom web server - why not use [butterflies](https://xkcd.com/378/)?

Comment: @BoristheSpider [**Of course**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosling_Emacs)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **for the sake of usability**.

- DAOs resolve access to database objects.
- Servlets must be used merely as a facade to handle remote requests and responses (typically HTTP).

Servlets are aimed to do the parsing/formatting of parameters; but they must not know anything about business logic.

So, an intermediate level of **business logic classes** is necessary between servlets and DAOs. Classes from this level must know the business rules, the database schema and how to use it. This business logic must not be coupled to any deployment schema, so it can be used (and reused) from a number of facades:

- servlets/jsps,
- swing guis,
- spring controllers,
- Ant tasks,
- etc.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175950/in-mvc-dao-should-be-called-from-controller-or-model) is a stackexchange thread that may help with some explanation.

Comment: Great explanation, makes perfect sense. Thank you!